# How to get each group of duplicate values of some columns into new seperate dataframes

Tags: python, dataframe

let's say that I have this dataframe

```
    length  width   output
0   1.5 0.20    3
1   1.5 0.20    3
2   1.2 0.15    4
3   1.2 0.15    5
4   3.0 1.10    1
5   2.0 1.00    3
6   2.0 1.00    4
```

I want to loop on the data frame and check if there is rows that have identical values of length and width and have different output and write it into a new dataframe. For example I want my output to two separate dataframes the first one is:

```
    length  width   output
2   1.2 0.15    4
3   1.2 0.15    5
```

and the second one is:

```
5   2.0 1.00    3
6   2.0 1.00    4
```

Answer (score 2):

This will loop the dataframe and search for groups that have more than one unique value:

```
for _, g in df.groupby(['length', 'width']):
    if g['output'].nunique() > 1:
        d = pd.DataFrame(g)
        print(d)
        print('-' * 80)
```

Prints:

```
   length  width  output
2     1.2   0.15       4
3     1.2   0.15       5
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   length  width  output
5     2.0    1.0       3
6     2.0    1.0       4
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
df[df['length'].str.extract(r'(\w+)\s(\w+)')[0]==df['length'].str.extract(r'(\w+)\s(\w+)')[1]]
```

If two are different columns:

```
for x,y in df.groupby(['length', 'width']):
    if y['output'].nunique() > 1:
        print(pd.DataFrame(y))
```